# How does a web page knows when I interact with an element if it has no event handlers?

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

I was trying to use a `WebBrowser` to scrape [this website](http://www.oo.com.au/DVDs_CDs_and_Entertainment_C62.cfm?sort=NewestFirst) and tried to programmatically change the amount of displayed pages to 200. If you manually change the value of the drop down menu, it will refresh the results to show whatever amount of results you select, but if you do it with injected JavaScript (since the `WebBrowser` allows injecting JavaScript code into your local copy of the page), the value will change but the page will not refresh.

I also tried firing the `onchange` event by using `menu.onchange()` and `menu.fireEvent("onchange")` (where `menu` is the `select` element), but nothing happened. Then I just went through every event (at least that's what I think) in the `select` element by doing a `for..in` loop and displaying every item that starts with `on...` this way:

```
for(var i in menu)
{
    if(("" + i).indexOf("on") == 0) alert("" + i + " => " + menu[i])
}
```

And I noticed every single event was `null`. How is it possible for the page to know I'm changing the value if every event is `null`?

I did find a workaround and did it another way, and probably using a `WebBrowser` is not the best way to scrape this site. But I'm really curious about the above and *not* looking for a solution on how to scrape this site anymore.

Comment: There are ways to attach event handlers that don't set any attributes of the element.

Comment: You can change the control to 200 with injected javascript or in your own browser but you're only doing it client side. That value of 200 is not being sent to the server so when the server runs it's query on how many items to populate it only sees 50 because only your client has 200 showing. That's the beauty and the mess of client side, you can change displays and all sorts of things around locally but it doesnt register on the server.

Comment: @Pointy: Can you give me a quick example?

Comment: In Internet Explorer, there's "attachEvent".  In other browsers, there's "addEventListener".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page uses jQuery to bind a `change` event handler to the element. The `change` event handler submits the parent form. The following can be found in `main.js`, lines 268-272:

```
var pagingControls = $('.page_size select');
if(pagingControls.length >= 1)
{
    pagingControls.change( function(){ this.parentNode.submit();})
}
```

Binding an event handler this way will not cause a property to be changed on the element itself, which is why nothing showed up when you looked at the `on...` properties.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Just a quick clarification needed: is that `change` method in the `pagingControls` that is receiving the anonymous function a jQuery method or a JavaScript one? If a jQuery one, do you have any idea how is jQuery binding the event handler so that it doesn't show up as a property of the element?

Comment: It's a jQuery method. `pagingControls` is a jQuery object so it will only have jQuery methods. You can bind event handlers without using an attribute on the element, for example: `element.onchange = function() { ... }`

Comment: @jsoldi jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call server side event use like this `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpType").InvokeMember("onchange");`

where onchanged is server side event